# InDesign: ExtendScript to list fonts and extended font information

Tags: adobe-indesign, extendscript

I need to list detailed information about the fonts used in a set of inDesign documents. The information I need is essentially accessible through the menu item **Type › Find Fonts…** (as explained [here](https://creativepro.com/indesigns-font-manager/)) but going through each font in every document and writing down the information is not feasible.

I can find much of the information in the `Font` objects under`document.fonts` and my question is how to access or generate the extended properties found in the panel below:

- Character count for the given font
- Pages where the font occurs

[image: 1]
<sub>(source: [indesignsecrets.com](https://indesignsecrets.com/wp-content/uploads/2008/04/moreinfo.jpg))</sub>

Edit: The `document.fonts` array also doesn't seem to include missing fonts.

Comment: Try this script. The Description is in german. It says it exports all used fonts in the document. http://indesign.hilfdirselbst.ch/ausgabe-export/liste-mit-schriften-im-dokument-ausgeben.html

Comment: The script will not export the character count and pages for the fonts but otherwise a useful script. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, here's a brute-force strategy for character counting. It iterates through every <strike>character</strike> textStyleRange in the document and checks its applied font. **Edit:** Updated to use textStyleRanges. Much faster than going through every character.

```js
var document = app.open(new File(Folder.desktop.fsName + "/test/test.indd"));
try {
    var fontMultiset = countCharsInFonts(document);

    // For each font, display its character count.
    var fonts = document.fonts.everyItem().getElements();
    for (var i = 0; i < fonts.length; i++) {
        var fontName = fonts[i].fullName;
        $.writeln(fontName + ": " + fontMultiset[fontName]);
    }
}
finally {
    document.close();
}

function countCharsInFonts(document) {
    // Create the font multiset.
    var fontMultiset = {
        add: function add(fontName, number) {
            if (this.hasOwnProperty(fontName)) {
                this[fontName] += number;
            }
            else {
                this[fontName] = number;
            }
        },
    };

    // For every textStyleRange in the document, add its applied font to the multiset.
    var stories = document.stories.everyItem().getElements();
    for (var i = 0; i < stories.length; i++) {
        var story = stories[i];
        var textStyleRanges = story.textStyleRanges.everyItem().getElements();
        for (var j = 0; j < textStyleRanges.length; j++) {
            fontMultiset.add(textStyleRanges[j].appliedFont.fullName, textStyleRanges[j].length);
        }
    }

    // For any fonts that aren't applied in the document, set the character count to 0.
    var fonts = document.fonts.everyItem().getElements();
    for (var i = 0; i < fonts.length; i++) {
        var fontName = fonts[i].fullName;
        if (!fontMultiset.hasOwnProperty(fontName)) {
            fontMultiset[fontName] = 0;
        }
    }

    return fontMultiset;
}
```

Comment: Splendid! The `document.fonts` array seems to be pretty useless and `fontName` is not accessible for missing fonts but building the set by iterating through `textStyleRanges` using the `name` property did the trick for counting the characters. As for the page numbers I'm not sure how `textStyleRanges` are connected to `Page` objects. Any ideas on that?

Comment: I don't know if `textStyleRanges` or `stories` can be directly connected to pages because they can span multiple pages. Perhaps for each page you could get the `textFrames`, and get the `textStyleRanges` inside each `textFrame`.

Comment: We're close enough to a solution and I'll get back with the code next week. I really appreciate your help dln385!